# Javascript timed downloads

Tags: javascript, html

So i'm trying to use a script to time downloads on my site and i've been having trouble changing what it does when the timer is at 0. This is the code:

```
        else{ 
        //After the counter download the file and end the timer 
        document.getElementById("time").innerText = "Now"; 
        download(); 
        return; 
    }
```

Now instead of it saying "Now" and auto downloading with "download();" how do i make it show a hyperlink instead of the "Now"?
All help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!
-Matt.

Comment: how do i make it return a hyperlink instead of saying "Now"?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you are asking, but here goes...

```
var link = "http://link_to_download";     
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "<a href = " + link + ">Now</a>;
```

Comment: 1. `innerText` is not standard (doesn't work in Firefox, for example). 2. Setting the text won't create links AFAIK. I'd use `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `a` element, and set its `onclick` event to your download function:

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.onclick = download;
link.innerHTML = "Download";
link.href = "#";

var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "images/site_logo.gif";
img.height = 54;
img.onmouseover = function() { this.src = 'images/logo.png'; };
img.onmouseout = function() { this.src = 'images/site_logo.gif'; };
link.appendChild(img);

document.getElementById("time").appendChild(link);
```

- Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D5qr7/2/
- With image:  http://jsfiddle.net/D5qr7/4/

Comment: +1, but isn't the `onclick` property supposed to receive a function object? In that case `link.onclick = download;` would suffice I guess.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté ah, thanks.  I couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté then innerHTML it is!

Comment: Heh. `=]` Well, if you want to keep away from the `innerHTML`, you can use `link.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Download'));` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/D5qr7/3/)), but yeah both work.

Comment: @dbaseman
Sorry to ask a more complicated question but is there any way to put this in there: [code] <img src="images/site_logo.gif" height="54" onmouseover="this.src='images/logo.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/site_logo.gif'" /> [/code] instead of it saying "Download"?